# problemas al realizar consulta con codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hago un reporte de ventas por productos en el cual se debe listar todos los productos vendidos con la cantidad, el proveedor, el precio de venta, precio de costo y el total. con la consulta q les mustros no me retorna nada. Alguien puede hecharme una manita??

**Esta es la Tabla donde se debe mostrar los datos**

```
 <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>

                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>Nombre Producto:</th>
                          <th>Proveedor:</th>
                          <th>Cant. Vendida:</th>
                          <th>stock Actual:</th>
                          <th>Pr. Ult. Compra:</th>
                          <th>Venta Total:</th>
                          <th>Opciones:</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php if (!empty($ventas)):?>
                        <?php foreach($ventas as $venta):?>
                          <tr>

                            <td> <?php echo $productos->id_producto;?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $productos->nombre_producto;?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $productos->proveedoro;?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $productos->cantidad;?></td>
                            <td> <?php echo $productos->pCosto_producto;?></td>
                            <td> monto</td>
                            <?php $dataVentas = $venta->id_ventas."*".$venta->nombres_cliente."*".$venta->tComprobante."*".$venta->fecha_ventas."*".$venta->subtotal_ventas."*".$venta->descuento_ventas."*".$venta->iva_ventas."*".$venta->total_ventas;?>
                            <td> <div class ="btn-group">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-view-ventas" data-toggle="modal" 
                                      data-target="#modal-default" value="<?php echo $venta->id_ventas;?>">
                                      <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                                  </button>
                          </tr>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                      <?php endif;?>        
                      </tbody>
                       <tfoot>
                          <tr>
                              <th style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                              <th></th>
                          </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

**Este el el controlador**

```
public function index()
{   $fechaInicio = $this->input->post("fechainicio");
    $fechaFin = $this->input->post("fechafin");
    if ($this->input->post("buscar")) //pregunta si se presiono el boton buscar
    {
        $productos = $this->Ventas_models->getVentasProductosByDate($fechaInicio, $fechaFin);

    }
    else
    {
        $productos = $this->Ventas_models->getVentasProductos();

    }
    $data = array
    (
        'productos' => $productos, // se carga en el array la variable ventas q se obtuvo en el if de arriba 

    );
    $this->load->view("layouts/header");
    $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
    $this->load->view("admin/reportes/Rep_Productos", $data);
    $this->load->view("layouts/footer");
}
```

**El MOdelo**

```
public function getVentasProductos()
{
    $this->db->select("dv.*,sum(dv.cantidad_detalle_ventas) as cantidad,p.nombre_producto,p.proveedor_id_producto,p.stock_producto,pro.nombre_proveedores as proveedor");
    $this->db->from("detalle_ventas dv");
    $this->db->join("productos p","dv.producto_id_detalle_ventas = p.id_producto");
    $this->db->join("proveedores pro","p.proveedor_id_producto = pro.id_proveedores");
    //$this->db->join("tipo_comprobante tc","v.tipo_comprobante_id_ventas = tc.id_tComprobante");
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    if ($resultados->num_rows()>0) 
    {
        return $resultados->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Por lo que veo no estás cargando el modelo en el controlador, por lo que al llamar a sus funciones te va a dar fallo. ¿Lo cargas en algún otro lado donde no lo veamos? Si no con hacer un **$this->load->model('ruta_de_tu_modelo');** antes de las llamadas a las funciones del modelo te las debería de cargar.

Comment: si lo cargue en el constructor @PHPMyguel !! estoy trancado realmente.. jaja.. gracias igual por la respuesta amigo!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada en tu controlador antes de cargar tus view realiza un `var_dump()` de `$data` para que veas si te esta retornando un `false` o si te esta retornando algo, otro punto es que al momento de que tu estas mostrando tus datos en el `view` haciendo el `foreach()` lo estas haciendo con objetos y los valores no los estas retornando con objetos desde el `model`, basta con poner `result_object()` en lugar de `result()` o de `result_array()`.

No se en que momento estas creando el `array` de nombre `ventas` para recorrerlo con el `foreach()` pero en este caso mas bien tendrías que recorrer el `array` de nombre `productos`.

Tu error esta en que tienes las condiciones del `Join` volteadas.

Controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    $fechaInicio = $this->input->post("fechainicio");
    $fechaFin = $this->input->post("fechafin");
    if ($this->input->post("buscar")) {
        $productos = $this->Ventas_models->getVentasProductosByDate($fechaInicio, $fechaFin);
    } else {
        $productos = $this->Ventas_models->getVentasProductos();
    }
    $data['productos'] = $productos;
    $this->load->view("layouts/header");
    $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
    $this->load->view("admin/reportes/Rep_Productos", $data);
    $this->load->view("layouts/footer");
}
```

Modelo:

```
public function getVentasProductos()
{
    $this->db->select('dv.*, sum(dv.cantidad_detalle_ventas) as cantidad, p.nombre_producto, 
                       p.proveedor_id_producto, p.stock_producto, pro.nombre_proveedores as proveedor');
    $this->db->from('detalle_ventas dv');
    $this->db->join('productos p', 'p.id_producto = dv.producto_id_detalle_ventas');
    $this->db->join('proveedores pro', 'pro.id_proveedores = p.proveedor_id_producto');
    $result = $this->db->get();
    if (!$result->num_rows() == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $result->result_object();
}
```

Comment: Gracias x tu respuesta, efectivamente el array que estaba recorriendo no era el correcto. Muy agradecido x la ayuda. ahora como veras soy nuevo en esto y  me sigue costando un poco, por lo que quería provechar tu amabilidad y hacerte otra consulta `sum(dv.cantidad_detalle_ventas) as cantidad` me suma toda la columna como podria hacer para q me sume solo los q tengan el `id_producto` que este trabajando? y otra, solo me muestra un registro no me muestra los demas productos. gracias x tu atencion amigo mi correo el elvio.britos@gmail.com x si haga falta.

Comment: Me gustaría que formularas otra pregunta con todos esos pequeños detalles que tienes pero que te tomes tu tiempo para redactarla y poner lo que te interesa obtener y donde tienes problemas. Para seguir las normas del sitio y con mucho gusto la verificamos.

Comment: gracias amigo, ahora mismo!!